# Full text search in solr embedded in datastax

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have a graph and i put search index on different properties of vertices in that graph. Now i want to implement full text search(like google) on vertices of that graph. I have tried using copyField but it's not working because for each search index dse implement different core in solr. how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the next release of DSE Graph, Search cores are controlled through Gremlin only.  This means you have the options for Searching based on what's outlined here - https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/useSearchIndexes.html.  In an upcoming release we will enable users to manage a Core directly to provide more customization of Search analysis chains.

If you have additional questions, I recommend you hop into the DSE Professional Community Graph Slack room here - https://academy.datastax.com/slack